# how to use angular with mobile events recognition

Tags: angularjs, events, jquery-mobile, mobile, angular-ui

I tried using hammer.js alongside with ngHammer to recognize mobile events but it's not working so hot. distinguishing between tap/double tap is arbitrary and a little fuzzy and some other events weren't working as I expected.

Did anyone else experience something like this with ngHammer and found a solution or can recommend me on a nice and simple solution for mobile events recognition?

So far jquery-mobile-events looks pretty good but it needs to be combined with other solutions for pinch and rotate.

Comment: Add code blocks and explain the point where you are facing the issue.

Comment: Baba, looks like angular-gestures is also based on hammer.js but much more popular, you might want to check it out: https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures

Comment: godblessya bubba! :D